# Sites with guides or blogs about installing Linux on low-end or low resource hardware

Tags: system-installation, distro-recommendation

I'm looking for a website where people share stories and guidance on successfully installing Linux distros on low-end and low resource PCs or other devices (Raspberry Pi for example). I prefer Ubuntu

I need an OS to install on a laptop and a desktop machine that both came out with Windows XP.

The laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad R61i, Pentium Dual Core, 1GB DDR2 ram, Intel Family GPU. I installed 12.04 and it's very slow

The desktop is a custom build, Pentium 4 775 socket, 512MB DDR ram, Nvidia 8800GTS discrete card.

Comment: Your question may be more suited for http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: And your question may just be a variant of those found when you do a Google search with `old computers site:askubuntu.com`

Comment: could be, but ubuntu is also a linux distro and as mentioned in question. ubuntu is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looking for a blog when you could just try the OS yourself?

Lubuntu and Xubuntu are the lightweight variants of Ubuntu. [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) has a few more features than Lubuntu, but it is still very lightweight and speedy on midrange old computers. It would work very well on either of the two systems you mentioned. [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is even more lightweight.

Both will get you the same support and available software that plain old Ubuntu does, because they are official variants.

Comment: Tried Lubuntu 12.04. it was running as slow as Ubuntu 12.04. Was trying Debian and PuppyLinux but they didnt come with a wireless driver. so i was bummed.

Comment: 1. Is it the Live CD that's slow, or did you try installing? 2. What is slow? Trying to push the hardware beyond what it's designed to do will cause hangups and/or slowness no matter what the OS.

Comment: lubuntu installed speed is the same as ubuntu install speed. this is on a intel pentium dual core, 1GB DDR2, laptop..

Comment: But again, what is being slow? How far can you push the machine before you start to notice lag?